# Is there data on increased wear when using resin only rotors with sintered pads?

Tags: disc-brake, rotor

I'm after hard numbers here, not woolly descriptions. Of course it will vary with riding conditions, but I can extrapolate from numbers and not vague words.

I always use sintered pads in the BB5s on my tourer and I'm very happy with them (I ride a lot of steep narrow roads that require descending on the brakes, sometimes laden). My main wheelset is 6-bolt, but I've got a spare set that's centerlock. I could only find stock of tourney rotors, which say "resin only".

I've reluctantly ordered some resin pads, but they might not come in time for when I need to use the front wheel. Anyway, it's only my spare wheelset, and I'd probably never wear out the rotors if they were properly hardened. I'd rather not have to keep track of changing pads when I change wheels.

I've seen mentions of "less hardened" steel, but even if it wears 50% faster, that's no big deal and ordering the resin pads was a waste. If it wears 10x faster, that becomes a safety issue as I'm expecting to use the spare wheels for a good few hundred km while my dynamo hub is being serviced.

So has anyone quantified the extra wear using sintered pads on resin-only rotors as compared to universal rotors?

Comment: Maybe it requires a test rig to compare two new rotors?  Perhaps with two calipers plumbed to the same lever so the pressure is equal, on a wheel with two rotors.

Comment: @Criggie that would be a pretty extreme test. As always I'd like to get the chance to try it myself.  I hoped for something like "I bought some once and they wore out in 6 months of commuting when I'd expect a year".  If I get some time I'll think about testing something, but I don't get fast wear with my sintered pads on universal 6-bolt rotors (ceramic wore the rotors around 10x faster than sintered). But apart from a weekend with a couple of short hilly rides, it's straight into a 700km week so I'm not inclined to push it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the data-based answer you're looking for, but you will probably not find it because the problem with metallic or semi-metallic pads on Shimano resin-only rotors is they screech and the rotors get torn up rapidly. What I've seen them do is develop bad circular grooves. It really doesn't work at all.

Comment: To clarify, it's the metallic pads that get torn up rapidly on the resin-only rotor? Or are you saying the metal pads are noisy and the resin-only rotor gets tore up?

Comment: @Jeff edited. It's the rotors.